# Getting error Cannot POST /public/register-controller on submitting the form

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am creating and login signup system using express js mysql and node js, so as soon as i click on submit button i get an error as :

> Cannot POST /public/register-controller

my index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>SignUp</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="signup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="masthead">
            <div class="boards-menu"></div>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><i class="fab fa-trello logo-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Trello</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section class="signup-login">
            <form action="/public/register-controller" method="POST">
                <div class="username">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="name"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="username">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="eamil"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="username">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="button-signup-login">
                    <button class="add-card-btn btn">Sign Up</button>
                    <a class="signup-navigator" href="login.html">already a
                        user?</a>
                </div>

            </form>
        </section>

    </body>

    </html>
```

my config.js

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'trello',
    password: 'trello',
    database: 'trello'
});
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected");
    } else {
        console.log("Error while connecting with database");
    }
});
module.exports = connection;
```

my index.js

```
 var express = require("express");
    var path = require('path');


    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var connection = require('./config');
    var app = express();

    var authenticateController = require('./public/authenticate-controller');
    var registerController = require('./public/register-controller');
    var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.static(dir));
    /* route to handle login and registration */
    app.post('/api/register', registerController.register);
    app.post('/api/authenticate', authenticateController.authenticate);

    console.log(authenticateController);
    app.post('/public/register-controller', registerController.register);
    app.post('/public/authenticate-controller', authenticateController.authenticate);
    app.listen(8012);
```

my register-controller.js

```
var connection = require('/home/codemymobile/study/trello/config');
var Cryptr = require('cryptr');
var express = require("express");
var cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');
module.exports.register = function (req, res) {
    var encryptedString = cryptr.encrypt(req.body.password);
    var sql = 'insert into users(name, email, password) values ?';
    var values = [[req.body.name, req.body.email, encryptedString]];
    connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
        res.status(200).send({ error: false, message: "User has been created successfully" });
    });
};
```

my authenticate-controller.js

```
var Cryptr = require('cryptr');
cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');

var connection = require('./../config');
module.exports.authenticate = function (req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;


    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                status: false,
                message: 'there are some error with query'
            });
        } else {

            if (results.length > 0) {
                decryptedString = cryptr.decrypt(results[0].password);
                if (password == decryptedString) {
                    res.json({
                        status: true,
                        message: 'successfully authenticated'
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        status: false,
                        message: "Email and password does not match"
                    });
                }

            }
            else {
                res.json({
                    status: false,
                    message: "Email does not exits"
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

so any help that why my file is not getting the path of register-contoller and i am getting this error, please help me out i am quite new to node and express

Comment: Hey, could you please explain why do you have 2 express servers running on the same port? Are theese two different machines?

Comment: @Hasta Dhana you are talking about service.js and index.js port? actually i am quite new so  i thought it should be the same

Comment: should i change them ?

Comment: if i change the port numbeer then i am getting an error as ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'email' cannot be null

Comment: you've wrongly mention me instead of @smolus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made a smaller mistake that is in the html form you are using eamil instead of email in name i.e name="eamil" instead of name="email", either change it here or else change the name you are calling in your js files